# Longest Palindromic Substring: solution is not optimized

Tags: c++, performance

I decided to write a solution for the Longest Palindromic Substring using more declarative (IMO) style as opposed to a C-style code.
One of C++'s idioms is "zero-cost abstraction", so I expected this code to be optimized and have a runtime performance identical to a C-styled version.
But my expectations were not met, and this code is 8 times slower.

Here is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using std::string;

class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        if (s.empty())
            return {};

        const auto sv = std::string_view(&s[0], s.size());
        const auto getPalindrome = [sv](size_t index) noexcept -> std::string_view {
            const auto getPalindrome = [sv](std::string_view lps, int iL, int iR) noexcept -> std::string_view {
                for (; iL >= 0 && 
                    iR < sv.size() &&
                    sv[iL] == sv[iR];
                    --iL, ++iR)
                {
                    const auto lenght = size_t(iR - iL + 1);
                    if (lps.size() < lenght)
                        lps = std::string_view(&sv[iL], lenght);
                }

                return lps;
            }; 

            const auto lpsUneven = getPalindrome(std::string_view(&sv[index], 1), int(index), int(index));
            const auto lpsEven = getPalindrome(std::string_view{}, int(index) - 1, int(index));

            return std::max(lpsEven, lpsUneven, [](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs){ return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); });
        };
        
        std::string_view lps{};
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
            lps = std::max(lps, getPalindrome(i), [](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs){ return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); });

        return std::string(lps);
    }
};
```

Leetcode shows that it runs for 67 ms. All the submissions that run 9 ms are C-style code.
However, it shows 6.9Mb memory consumption, which beats 90% of submissions. But it doesn't excuse 8 times slower runtime.

Can someone explain, what makes this code so slow? What prevents it from optimization?

---

Usage of ternary operator instead of 'if' improves runtime (48 ms)

```
const auto length = size_t(iR - iL + 1);
lps = lps.size() < length ? sv.substr(iL, length) : lps;
```

Why...

Comment: Your leetcode submission URL is a deadlink: "Submission does not exist". (Yes, I understand that creating / maintaining site-specific credentials may yield an alternate page; that doesn't change the fact that for StackExchange the URL is a deadlink.) Consider pasting the relevant text into a Gist or into a GitHub repo, or someplace that archive.org is capable of crawling. Bit rot happens, and soon enough it turns useful discussion pages into useless ones when the context disappears.

Comment: @J_H I removed the link. The code for submission is identical

Comment: What is your C solution? How does that look like? The difference must come from something.

Comment: "Usage of ternary operator instead of 'if' improves runtime" - really? I don't think so. I rather think it's the difference between `string_view` and `substring`. Any evidence for your claim?

Comment: What is the input this is tested on?

Comment: @ThomasWeller optimized performance should be identical regardles of using `string_view` or `substring`. Ternary vs `if`, on the other hand, might have different performance: https://godbolt.org/z/zvY3P7rqb you can see loop unrolling for ternary, but not for `if`. Generated assembly is not identical for 2 versions. Hence I though that it is the case here.
Thanks to J_H I know that the code is missing an algorithmic optimization for case with repeating identical letters.

Answer (score 2):

```
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
```

This is a terrific signature.
The identifier `s` is well-chosen.
Nothing special about it; it's just a string, as the type describes.
Immediately we understand that and move on.

```
... [sv](std::string_view lps, int iL, int iR) ...
```

In contrast, this is just terrible.
Eventually we figure out the integers are indexLeft and indexRight.
Using iL and iR as local variables could be Fine and self-explanatory.
But a signature has a much higher documentation burden,
as it has to explain to potential callers what they should supply
and what semantics to expect.
Here the Gentle Reader doesn't get so much as a `//` comment
to suggest how to mentally pronounce these identifiers.

It took me a while to glean the meaning of the first TLA,
and I still don't know if Author's Intent is that I should
read it as

- longest palindrome string, or
- longest palendrome substring

Consider preferring a more descriptive identifier, such as `candidate`.

This, on the other hand, caused no cognitive speed-bump:

```
                    const auto lenght = size_t(iR - iL + 1);
```

Yes, there's a typo.
But the intent is still clear.
Do fix the typo.

You are apparently not using a linter or pretty-printer.
I encourage you to adopt a coding style (maybe GNU? or Google?)
and have a tool enforce it.

In particular, writing `if (c) foo();` instead of `if (c) { foo(); }`
is a well-known way of inviting maintainers to introduce
hard-to-diagnose bugs.
There's decades of hard-won experience behind that learning.
Don't discard it.

---

The OP is a question about elapsed running time,
which includes these two lines.

```
                    if (lps.size() < lenght)
                        lps = std::string_view(&sv[iL], lenght);
```

You complain that C++ is "slow" relative to C implementations.
I wonder if that assignment is more expensive than you expected.

OP did not include per-line profiling data.
From reading its text, it is hard to tell if view creation
is an interesting bottleneck or not.
Consider posting supplementary measurements.

---

Let's talk about the algorithm for a moment.
I have two remarks.

Consider a deliberately annoying input like ABBBB ... BBBC.
We're gonna scan IDK, a million B's.
Could we maybe scan them just once, rather than twice
as in the current code?
The odd / even distinction is *lovely* for creating
easily understood and debugged subroutines.
But maybe there's a performance requirement
that we drag those million bytes through
the L1 + L2 + L3 caching levels just *once*,
if we want to win.

I don't know what the input test vectors look like,
but maybe unigram analysis would help? (In the example above,
a linear scan shows that "B" is super popular, and {"A", "C"}
have just single counts.) Maybe look for n-grams plus
their inverted n-grams? ("AB" + "BA" above, or
tri-grams "ABB" + "BBA".)

---

Overall?

This code appears to achieve its design objectives.
We have an existence proof that it *could* go faster,
and there are several avenues worth exploring
which hold the promise of lower time complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Regarding `if (c) foo();` I see nothing criminal if theres a simple and short statement on a new line with an indent

Comment: I understand. Wait six months. Hire several maintenance engineers of diverse abilities. Task them with features and bug fixes. Wait for the bug reports to roll in. Pay the costs. Is it a simple thing? Sure. Have various code bases been badly impacted by missing braces and misleading indent levels? Oh, yes! We could instruct all those individuals to "always be careful!" Or we could choose to adopt development practices with lower expected cost based on historic case studies. The example you set is the example that future maintainers will follow.

Comment: Is it based on a research or an anecdotal evidence? Because there are people, who don't perceive same-line braces very well. And it also can cause a lot of confusion. 
For a production code I usually use auto formatting with clang-format

Comment: I have personally had too many conversations with colleagues who pushed bad code into production when they didn't attend to whether braces were needed. I guess there's a reason I left the C world behind decades ago in favor of python indenting, where the whitespace that humans perceive is semantically relevant during byte compilation. (Well, that and Undefined Behavior.) A git merge gone bad can _look_ right. Even common lisp / scheme source tends to be more readable than C when the C source can include / omit braces at random. When man and machine see things differently, that spells trouble.